# How do I type the independence symbol in Mathematica?

Tags: symbols, built-in-symbols

I know this seems to be a really stupid question, but I can't find a way to type the independent symbol. I found how to write the `\[UpTee]` but it isn't the same. This is the symbol for independence: ⫫. This is the symbol I get using `\[Uptee]`: ⊥.

Comment: can you add a picture of it?

Comment: You could do `uptee = ⫫`, then add it with `uptee`.

Comment: Probably you should ask Wolfram to include the double uptack as part of their unicode support:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aeb/index.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there does not seem to have a [UpTee] here is a ugly solution

```
ut = Row[{Rotate[Style["\[DoubleRightTee]", 20, Bold], 120.95]}];
 Row[{Style["x "], Style[ut] , Style[" y"]}]
```

Hope it will be usefull

Answer (score 4):

The character you are looking for is the unicode character DoubleUpTack, which can be typed in as `\:2aeb`.

Comment: it is probably worth noting that one might need to change the font to actually see the character, for me on windows the default font has no entry for that codepoint...

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want to use it for, this might help:

```
independence = Style[\:2aeb, FontFamily -> "Cambria Math"]
```